# Program (application) not running on iPhone using xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have upgraded my iPhone OS from 6.0.1 to 6.1.2, and now when I run my program (application) in Xcode, I get this error message:

> "No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

Previously all my applications were running properly, but now I can't run any on my iPhone using Xcode. Is there a problem with my provisioning profiles? I have added my device again in the Provisioning Portal, but still I don't have a solution.

Is there any way to run my application (program) on my iPhone?

or how can I downgrade my iPhone OS to 6.0.1?

I dont have SHSH blobs saved and I have tried other methods also... none of them worked for me...

Comment: You need to update your version of Xcode

Comment: is it so that 4.5.2 will not support iOS 6.1.2?

Comment: Yes Raju it will not support, You need to upgrade your Xcode

Comment: but according to my company requirement the application will support only iOS 4.3 to 6..

Comment: It seems unwise not to support the latest operating system, and you're going to have to upgrade eventually anyhow.

Comment: ok does xcode 4.6 works on MAC OS X 10.7.5?

Comment: @Raju yes Xcode 4.6 works on MAC OS X 10.7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't downgrade your iOS version on your device. What version of Xcode and iOS SDK are you using? Make sure you're using the latest (Xcode 4.6).

Comment: is it so that 4.5.2 will not support iOS 6.1.2?

Comment: I don't believe so. You need the iOS 6.1 SDK.

Comment: i have iOS SDK of 6.0.1.. but i searched in google and i came to know that SHSH blobs should be present.. but i dont have it..

Comment: I'm answering with the assumption that your device isn't jailbroken.

Comment: i did that also.. but after that Cydia get installed and it also not having SHSH of older version..

Comment: I can't help you with a jailbroken device, but I'm pretty sure all you need to do to solve your problem is update Xcode.

Comment: ok thanks a lot.. i will update Xcode and get back to u ok..:)

Answer (score 2):

in addition to upgrading your xCode , you will have to update your provisioning profile  in order to update your test phone iOS version.

Answer (score 1):

install the latest Xcode version 4.6. Xcode 4.2 does not support iPhone OS 6.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

You must update your sdk and simulitar versions.In the xcode's menu，choose xcode->Preferences...,and it
will open a window.You can choose the "Downloads" item,upgrade the components and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need Xcode 4.6 to run on the latest iOS version 6.1.2. I had the same issue with my device but after upgrading it has worked fine. Nothing to do with the jailbroken thing. Obviously you cannot downgrade the iPhone OS, so only option is to upgrade Xcode.

Hope I helped.